# Crypto encrypt with external IV

Tags: apex, javascript, encryption, crypto

how can I achieve the same result from the bellow JS to apex? I already have tried:

```
blob encryptedData = Crypto.encrypt('AES128', AesKey, AesIv, json); //apex
```

but it says 'Invalid initialization vector. Must be 16 bytes'.

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(AesKey);
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(AesIv);
    var date = new Date();
    var json = "{'key':'" + apiKey + "','time':'" + date.toISOString() + "'}";
    var authTokenEncrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(json), key,
        {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
      });
```

The key and IV, are exactly the same from the JS. Sadly, I can't provide the exactly values of key, so that you can reproduce, but yes, the AesIv has more than 16 bits and the AesKey is exactly 16 bits. Whit the JS code, I don't receive this error and encrypt normally.

Comment: Can you post bit of more code on those parameters which are passing through `Crypto.encrypt()`

Comment: hello @SantanuBoral, thank you, I added more comments, please, let me know if helps.